# Help for unpacking software

Tags: disassembly, debugging, decompilation, unpacking

I try to unpacking a software packed with PC guard 5 there are few month and i dont arrive manually or with script to find OEP. I readed many tutorials on it but dont worked. 
Can you help me please ?

Comment: I put the link of software on a shared site : https://transfer.pcloud.com/download.html?code=5ZywEmZF6de6HlvEMkZepp0ZWLguT2hqlzukaTp0JQRzwHtQsQk7. Can you Help me to unpack it please. I can pay for it. I need it. Please Help me.

Comment: Nobody cant Help me ?